# Angular TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

what I am trying to do is separate two methods. But that presents me with an issue. As I'm trying to get a function to run on component init. I want to get the file name when I upload it and pass the data down from `uploadFile` to `getUrl` the `event.files[0]`.

I've been trying to declare a value with the others I have at the top, but can't as I get "Property 'file' is used before its initialization." error when I try to do that.

uploadService:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { User, NgAuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UploadService {
  constructor(private afStorage: AngularFireStorage, @Inject(NgAuthService) private user: User) { }
  file: File;
  url = '';
  iUser = this.user.uid;
  basePath = `/uploads/images/${this.iUser}`;

  //method to upload file at firebase storage
  async uploadFile(event: any) {
    this.file = event.files[0];
    const filePath = `${this.basePath}/${this.file.name}`;    //path at which image will be stored in the firebase storage
    await this.afStorage.upload(filePath, this.file);
    if (this.file) {
      this.getUrl();
    } else {
      console.log("Select a image please.")
    }
  }

  //method to retrieve download url
  async getUrl() {
    const filePath = `${this.basePath}/${this.file.name}`; // error is coming from here.
    const snap = this.afStorage.storage.ref(filePath);
    await snap.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
      this.url = url;  //store the URL
      console.log(this.url);
    });
  }
}
```

user-profile.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UploadService } from '../../storage/upload.service';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.scss'],
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public uploadService: UploadService,
    public afStorage: AngularFireStorage,
    ) { }

    image = this.uploadService.url;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uploadService.getUrl();
  }
}
```

Stacktrace error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at UploadService.<anonymous> (upload.service.ts:30)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at tslib.es6.js:76
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:1387)
    at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:72)
    at UploadService.getUrl (upload.service.ts:29)
    at UserProfileComponent.ngOnInit (user-profile.component.ts:19)
    at callHook (core.js:2526)
    at callHooks (core.js:2495)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2446)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:1390)
    at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:72)
    at UploadService.getUrl (upload.service.ts:29)
    at UserProfileComponent.ngOnInit (user-profile.component.ts:19)
    at callHook (core.js:2526)
    at callHooks (core.js:2495)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2446)
    at refreshView (core.js:9456)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10566)
```

I can provide more info or anything if needed.

Comment: Hi @Slash1y, welcome to StackOverflow. You declare variable `file: File;` in `UploadService`, but didn't assign value to it, thus it is `null` by default. And you will get **name of undefined** for `this.file.name` in `getUrl()` .

Comment: How do I solve this? As I need it for my project. I've tried some things, but no luck. @YongShun

Comment: @YongShun I wanted to use `this.file = event.files[0]` for it, but since I don't pass any events to the function it won't work. As that is something that I tried but won't work. I do provide the parameter `event: any` in the function when I wanted to use it. Could you provide a solution to this? Or is there something else I can use and get the same result?

Comment: Or since your `basePath` contains user id, you can retrieve all the files available in the basePath and generate download URL(s).

Comment: But thing is, I want to get this method called everytime I enter my user-profile component on the ngOnInit method. And that suddenly requires me to provide a parameter like ``filename: string`. If you look at the components code you can see what I mean with that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the method `getUrl()` expects `this.file.name` to be defined by the time it is called.

A simple fix would be to only call `getUrl()` when you know that the `name` property on `this.file` has a value, e.g.

```
if ( this.file && this.file.name ) {
  this.getUrl();
} else {
  console.log("Select a image please.")
}
```

or simpler using a null check

```
if ( this.file?.name ) {
  this.getUrl();
} else {
  console.log("Select a image please.")
}
```

Alternatively, you may want to call `getUrl()` regardless of whether you actually have a file returned in the line `this.file = event.files[0];`. In this case you need to guarantee that `this.file.name` is not empty; the simplest way to do that would be to create a default / fallback value for either `this.file.name`, or even `this.file`.

```
// Fallback for this.file.name
async getUrl() {
    const filePath = `${this.basePath}/${this.file.name || 'fallback-filename'}`; // will not error, if undefined will use 'fallback-filename' instead.
    const snap = this.afStorage.storage.ref(filePath);
    await snap.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        this.url = url;  //store the URL
        console.log(this.url);
    });
}
```

or

```
// Fallback for this.file, i.e. instantiate file with some data and have that overwritten
file: File = {
    name: 'fallback-filename',
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I might have confused some people. But I wanted to always get the image on my web-app by running the `getUrl` function on the `ngOnInit` function on my component.

Comment: I suppose my question would be, if `event.files[0]` was `undefined`, what would you expect `getUrl()` to do? In this case your code wouldn't know which filename to get so you would need to decide what you wanted to happen in that scenario, e.g. don't call `getUrl()`, throw an error, get a default file anyway, etc

Comment: Yeah I mean need to recode my `getUrl()` function. And take some things into account. I did just find a video that shows it how I want to do it.

Comment: I think I found a better solution, I just needed to use Firebase real-time database to store the link to the image. Which seems more feasible to use, so I don't have to complicate things.